# How to have same page destination between 2 different buttons using hero

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm right now trying to make a page that could be opened by two different buttons. So for example, In my home page there would be these buttons and when I press on it, it would open up a page. Then when I press the other button it would open the same page like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp (
      title: 'Navigation Basics',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FirstRoute(),
    )
  );
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column (
          children: <Widget> [ 
            Hero (
              tag: 'open',
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Open route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                );
              },
            ),
            ),
            Hero (
              tag: 'open',
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Open route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                );
              },
            ),
            )
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Hero (
          tag: 'open',
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But for some reason there is a problem. If I press these Buttons I am able to open the page but not go back. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to present minimum reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've now edited my answer.

Comment: You need Unique `hero` tag on same screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use Unique `hero` Tag.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final String open1 = 'open';
  final String open2 = 'open2';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Hero(
          tag: open1,
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Open route'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                          open: open1,
                        )),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Hero(
          tag: open2,
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Open route'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                          open: open2,
                        )),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ])),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final String open;

  SecondRoute({this.open});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Hero(
        tag: open,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have a small problem. When I press button number 2, the animation is applied to button number 1. How can I fix this?

Comment: animation between widget is based on hero tags - same tag means animation will happen in them. & here its button 1 with same tag name. if we do same tag for button 2 then framework get confused to which widget it need to animate.

Comment: so solve it pass the tags with navigator to next screen.